# PHP Mysql not Deleting rows

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Trying to be able to delete some rows from my database but no errors are returned from the statement and if I run the query in phpmyadmin it actually deletes the record. Also executing SELECT statements work with no issues.

The $oId param has an int value

```
$stmt =  $this->db->prepare('DELETE FROM tbl_bdays WHERE uniqueId = ?');
$stmt->bind_param("i", $oId);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
```

Comment: Have you verified `$oId` contains a valid ID? Try running the query directly in PHPMyAdmin, make sure no errors about foreign tables comes up.

Comment: Actually I return the value of $oId and it is fine,  has a value and exists on the database. Running the query on phpMyAdmin does delete the record.

Comment: @marijnz0r this isn't PDO but MySQLi. Please learn the difference before editing posts and adding tags.

Comment: @ToddDavies Check an edit is correct before approving it. This is not PDO.

Comment: @ByteHamster Check an edit is correct before approving it. This is not PDO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you table name is literally `table`, then its an error because `table` is a [reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)

If you really can't change the name then you'll need to wrap it with backticks:

```
DELETE FROM `table` WHERE uniqueId = ?
```

Comment: No, table name is not table, it is tbl_bdays, also tried with the backticks but still the query runs on phpMyAdmin but not from PHP.

Comment: @nizx then you should have clarified that earlier, add `$stmt->execute() or die($this->db->error);` and check, make sure you have enabled error reporting

Comment: Backticks did it. Weird as the SELECT and INSERT queries work without them.

Answer (score 0):

You have no error checking, you should be checking each step of the way for errors. Try this:

```
$stmt = $this->db->prepare('DELETE FROM tbl_bdays WHERE uniqueId = ?');
if ( ! $stmt) die('Error whilst preparing: '.$this->db->error);
if ( ! $stmt->bind_param("i", $oId)) die('Error whilst binding: '.$this->db->error);
if ( ! $stmt->execute()) die('Error whilst executing: '.$this->db->error);
$stmt->close();
```